# Не выводит свойства объекта в цикле

Tags: javascript

Есть пустой объект в который я записал два новых свойства **firstAdd и secondAdd**
по идее **цикл должен выводить пару ключ:значение через alert,** но этого почему-то не происходит.
**В чем проблема?**

```js
let obj = {
}

Object.defineProperties(obj,{
firstAdd: {value: 'Первый', writable: true},
secondAdd: {value:'Второй', writable: true},    
});

for (let values of Object.entries(obj)) {
 alert(values); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[По-умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#parameters), значение свойства `enumerable` установлено как `false`.

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) возвращает, только перечислимые свойства.

Так как в примере нет перечислимых свойств (таких, у которых `enumerable===true`) то ничего и не выводится.

Для исправления достаточно явно указать, что свойство является перечислимым.

```js
let obj = {
}

Object.defineProperties(obj,{
  firstAdd: {value: 'Первый', writable: true, enumerable: true},
  secondAdd: {value:'Второй', writable: true, enumerable: true},    
});

for (let values of Object.entries(obj)) {
 console.log(values); 
}
```

Comment: Воо! Спс за ответ!